# Avoid backslash-encoding utf8 characters when deriving Read (and Show) in Haskell

Tags: parsing, haskell, text, encoding, utf-8

I'm having trouble parsing utf8 characters into `Text` when deriving a `Read` instance. For example, when I run the following in *ghci*...

```
> import Data.Text
> data Message = Message Text deriving (Read, Show)
> read ("Message \"→\"") :: Message
Message "\8594"
```

Can I do anything to keep my text inside `Message` utf-8 encoded? I.e. The result should be...

```
Message "→"
```

(P.S. I already receive my serialized messages as `Text`, but currently need to `unpack` to a `String` in order to call `read`. I'd love to avoid this...)

**EDIT**: Ah sorry, answers rightly point out that it's `show` not `read` which converts to `"\8594"` - is there a way to `show` and convert back to `Text` again without the backslash encoding?

Comment: Personal pet peeve: \ is a backslash, and / is a forward slash, or just a slash.  I went ahead and edited your question to fix this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, the internal encoding used by `Text` (which is [actually UTF-16](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/text/0.11.2.3/doc/html/Data-Text.html#g:2))  is consistent and not exposed directly. If you want UTF-8, you can decode/encode a `Text` value as appropriate. Similarly, it doesn't make sense to talk about an encoding for `String`, because that's just a list of `Char`, where each `Char` is a unicode code point.

Most likely, it's only the `Show` instance for `Text` displaying things differently here.

Also, keep in mind that (by consistent convention in standard libraries) `read` and `show` are expected to behave as (de-)serialization functions, with a "serialized" format that, interpreted as a Haskell expression, describes a value equivalent to the one being (de-)serialized. As such, the slash encoding with ASCII text is often preferred for being widely supported and unambiguous. If you want to display a `Text` value with the actual code points, `show` isn't what you want.

---

I'm not entirely clear on what you want to do with the `Text`--using `show` directly is exactly what you're trying to avoid. If you want to display text in a terminal window that's going to dictate the encoding, and you want the stuff defined in `Data.Text.IO`. If you need to convert to a specific encoding for whatever other reason, `Data.Text.Encoding` will give you an encoded `ByteString` (emphasis on "byte", not "string"--a `ByteString` is a sequence of raw bytes, not a string of characters).

If you just want to convert from `Text` to `String` and back to `Text`... what's wrong with the slash encoding? `show` is not really intended for pretty-printing output for users to read, despite many people's initial expectations otherwise.

Comment: Oh you know, I'm using `show`/`read` to serialize/deserialize ADT's that deserialize again in JavaScript using https://github.com/rehno-lindeque/adt.js. However, you're quite right - I don't know what I'm thinking. Should be parsing the output of `show` directly to be as compatible as possible.

Comment: @RehnoLindeque: Yeah, working with the default `show` instance sounds like the least hassle to me, especially if your real goal is a form of interop (and that library does sound pretty neat, btw).

Comment: Thanks :) Yeah, wish I had more time to really clean it up... I'll do as suggested!